# startActivity(intent) causes error on Android

Tags: java, android

I did `onClick` at xml level. It was okay for a few times, but this one time causes error. I can't seem to find where the error is from. But it said that `startActivity(intent);` is where the error is.

```
  public void callNextSignUpScreen2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is my full code

```
public class SignUp2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variable
    ImageView back_icon;
    Button next, login;
    TextView title_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up2);

        //Hooks
        back_icon = findViewById(R.id.signup_back_btn);
        next = findViewById(R.id.signup_next_next_btn);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        title_text = findViewById(R.id.signup_title_text);

    }


    public void callNextSignUpScreen2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void callBackSign2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error is what?

Comment: I would make a try again after you replace the `getApplicationContext()` with `this`. Also we are going to need the error it says.

Comment: I have tried changing getApplicationContext to this, still there is error. supposedly that coding will take me to next class. But it got stuck there, 

this is the message
at 

com.example.cs1.Common.LoginSingup.SignUp2.callNextSignUpScreen2(SignUp2.java:39)

which i dont quite understand

Comment: Try SignUp2.this